# Step definition is not getting recognized in test runner

Tags: selenium, cucumber

``In  My Java cucumber setup -test runner Step definitions are not running.
Please find attached the screenshot of runner class,feature file and step definition locations.I am just launching the application
[image: Stepdefinitions]

```
  package com;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

public class StepDefinition {
    WebDriver driver;
    @Before

    public void setUp(){
         driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(){
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Given("^Launch the application$")
    public void loadUrl() throws Throwable {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

        throw new PendingException();
    }




}
```

Comment: Consider pasting the Step Definition within the Question area as text for further analysis.

Comment: I am just launching an URL:

Comment: @Bitz For the glue option value you need to give the path in terms of java package

Answer (score 1):

Segregate all your test runner classes in one package(com.tests) and all the step definition classes in another package(com.stepDefs). Then, glue the stepDefs package to each test runner.

I am using cucumber-junit 1.2.4 , that **@Cucumber.Options** syntax is **@CucumberOptions** for me.

template Syntax :

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features/", 
            tags = {"@soWeb"},
            plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber-html-report", 
                    "json:target/cucumber-json-report.json" 
                        },
            glue = "com.ba.StepDefs")

public class AltoroMutual_TestRunner {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

glue path argument to be either a package name or a class path(not a file system path). For example,

```
glue = {"com"}
```

or

```
glue = {"classpath:com"}
```

You are pointing to java file. change it accordingly.